# How can I select an xml node by Name and Number using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml structure:

```
<TacRef>        
    <TacRefData Num="0">    
        <MainData>
            <Name>Name 1</Name>
            <PicName>PicName 1</PicName>
        </MainData>
        <CategoryData Num="0">
            <CategoryTitle>General Information</CategoryTitle>
            <CategoryDescription>CategoryDescription 0</CategoryDescription>
        </CategoryData>
        <CategoryData Num="1">
            <CategoryTitle>Dimensions</CategoryTitle>
            <CategoryDescription>CategoryDescription 1</CategoryDescription>
        </CategoryData>
        <RwrData>
            <Index>0</Index>
            <Image>0</Image>
            <SearchTone>0</SearchTone>
            <LockTone>0</LockTone>
            <Name>No Radar</Name>
        </RwrData>
    </TacRefData>

    <TacRefData Num="1">    
        <MainData>
            <Name>Name 1</Name>
            <PicName>PicName 1</PicName>
        </MainData>
        <CategoryData Num="0">
            <CategoryTitle>General Information</CategoryTitle>
            <CategoryDescription>CategoryDescription 0</CategoryDescription>
        </CategoryData>
        <CategoryData Num="1">
            <CategoryTitle>Dimensions</CategoryTitle>
            <CategoryDescription>CategoryDescription 1</CategoryDescription>
        </CategoryData>
        <RwrData>
            <Index>0</Index>
            <Image>0</Image>
            <SearchTone>0</SearchTone>
            <LockTone>0</LockTone>
            <Name>No Radar</Name>
        </RwrData>
    </TacRefData>
</TacRef>
```

I am trying to get each node **Name** and CategoryData/CategoryDescription only for  Name containign "SA-" and CategoryData Num="4" (I did not show Num="4" in the example above)

I can find the Name containing "SA-" but **I do not know how to get only the CategoryData with Num="4".**

I am doing this:

```
  public class RefReader
    {
        private string _refFile = @"c:\....\TacRefDB.xml";
        public XmlDocument xDoc;

        public RefReader()
        {
            xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(_refFile);
            var nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("TacRef/TacRefData");
            foreach (XmlNode productNode in nodes)
            {
                var name = productNode["MainData"]["Name"].InnerXml;
                if (name.Contains("SA-"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    //here I want to get productNode["CategoryData"]["CategoryDescription"] with Num="4" => how do I do that?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using an XPath this should help: `/TacRef/TacRefData[MainData/Name[contains(text(), 'SA-')]]/CategoryData[@Num=4]/CategoryDescription/text()`. However, the example XML you have posted doesn't contain any matches for that

Comment: @Xerillio : I think with your query, you'll only get the `CategoryDescription` and not the `Name` and the `CategoryDescription`.

Comment: @dandan21 : You can test your XPATH queries here:  https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can get the **Name** and the **CategoryData/CategoryDescription** in one XPATH Query.

So modify the query below as you like, and try it :

```
//TacRefData[starts-with(./MainData/Name,'EC')]/(./MainData/Name|./CategoryData[@Num='0']/CategoryDescription)
```

The result would be :

[image]

Comment: If I wanted to serialize this into a class, how can I do this?
I all the examples I saw all the element nodes were unique.
In the example I supplied there are identical nodes with different number.
Can this be serialized automatically and if yes what kind of class would fit it, or perhaps I need to construct my own parser for such a class?

Comment: To serialize your XML you have to generate its schema first, and via the XSD.exe tool you can generate classes. Read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen and this one too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: You can use this online tool to generate the XML schema:  https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-to-xsd-converter